# Angular DataTable(grid) not binding with the given Json data

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8, angular-datatables

I am using angular datatable for displaying a grid in my form.

I **am able to bind the grid with static data** within the component.ts

However when I **am trying to bind the data from an API call the grid doesn't show up**.

Though my API is returning the data in the exact same way as my static data. 
I just have 1 week of experience in Angular, so i hope some one can help me in finding out what's wrong with my code.

this is my html

```html
 <div style="overflow-x:scroll; overflow-y:hidden; margin-bottom: 18px;">
    <table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" class="row-border hover grid"></table>
  </div>
```

This is my static data for which the grid binds.

```
dtUsers = [{"ProjectId":1,"Name":"SomeName","ProjectWaveId":0,"ProjectWave":"Unknown","ProjectServiceLineID":0,"ServiceLine":"Unknown or Undefined","MasterAccountID":"UNKNOWN","ClientID":0,"ClientName":"SomeClient","SeasonYear":0.0,"ImplementationContact":"UNKNOWN","CreatedBy":-1,"CreatedDt":"1900-01-01T00:00:00","ModifiedBy":-1,"ModifiedDt":"2019-03-22T15:55:26.413"}];
```

And this is the data returned from API

```
"[{"ProjectId":1,"Name":"SomeName","ProjectWaveId":0,"ProjectWave":"Unknown or Undefined","ProjectServiceLineID":0,"ServiceLine":"Unknown or Undefined","MasterAccountID":"UNKNOWN","ClientID":0,"ClientName":"SomeClient","SeasonYear":0.0,"ImplementationContact":"UNKNOWN","CreatedBy":-1,"CreatedDt":"1900-01-01T00:00:00","ModifiedBy":-1,"ModifiedDt":"2019-03-22T15:55:26.413"}]"
```

This is the part of code in the component.ts

```js
export class SearchProjectComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  dtUsers: any[];
  ngOnInit() {
    this.dtOptions = {
      data: this.dtUsers,
      columns: [{
          title: 'Project ID',
          data: 'ProjectId'
        },
        {
          title: 'Project Name',
          data: 'Name'
        },
        {
          title: 'Project Wave',
          data: 'ProjectWave'
        },
        {
          title: 'Service Line',
          data: 'ServiceLine'
        },
        {
          title: 'Master Account',
          data: 'MasterAccountID'
        },
        {
          title: 'Client',
          data: 'ClientName'
        },
        {
          title: 'Season Year',
          data: 'SeasonYear'
        },
        {
          title: 'Implementation contact',
          data: 'ImplementationContact'
        },
        {
          title: 'Modified By',
          data: 'ModifiedBy'
        },
        {
          title: 'Created By',
          data: 'CreatedBy'
        },
        {
          title: 'Modified Date',
          data: 'ModifiedDt'
        },
        {
          title: 'Created Date',
          data: 'CreatedDt'
        },
        {
          title: 'Action',
          data: null,
          defaultContent: `
            <button class="link-button">Edit</button>`
        }
      ]
    };
  }
  onSubmit() {
    debugger;
    console.log(1);
    this.searchservice.searchProjects(this.selectedFilters).subscribe(res => this.bindDataTable(res));
    this.dtTrigger.next();
  }

  bindDataTable(dt) {
    debugger;
    console.log(2);
    this.dtUsers = dt;
    this.dtOptions = {
      data: this.dtUsers,
      columns: [{
          title: 'Project ID',
          data: 'ProjectId'
        },
        {
          title: 'Project Name',
          data: 'Name'
        },
        {
          title: 'Project Wave',
          data: 'ProjectWave'
        },
        {
          title: 'Service Line',
          data: 'ServiceLine'
        },
        {
          title: 'Master Account',
          data: 'MasterAccountID'
        },
        {
          title: 'Client',
          data: 'ClientName'
        },
        {
          title: 'Season Year',
          data: 'SeasonYear'
        },
        {
          title: 'Implementation contact',
          data: 'ImplementationContact'
        },
        {
          title: 'Modified By',
          data: 'ModifiedBy'
        },
        {
          title: 'Created By',
          data: 'CreatedBy'
        },
        {
          title: 'Modified Date',
          data: 'ModifiedDt'
        },
        {
          title: 'Created Date',
          data: 'CreatedDt'
        },
        {
          title: 'Action',
          data: null,
          defaultContent: `
            <button class="link-button">Edit</button>`
        }
      ]
    };
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.dtTrigger.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to define the head and body of the table, check this: https://therichpost.com/angular-8-datatable-working-example/

Comment: That did work. Thank you. But i am still not sure why it doesnt work with declaring columns attribute in dtoptions. Both are effectively the same. And if i do have 50 columns in my grid it makes no sense to declare them as table headers in my html.

Comment: Maybe the issue is the structure, you need to check that, I can't find any example related to your solution way so I don't really sure what happened but it should be about the structure

Comment: Check that article, I think that is what do you want https://medium.com/@ct7/building-a-reusable-table-layout-for-your-angular-2-project-adf6bba3b498